# How to mock a class property in Magento 2 Unit Test

Tags: magento2, unit-tests, phpunit

How can I mock a class attribute such as a particular object (Ex: \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product)

Comment: Mocking a class attribute don't have a sense for me. Can you describe the example where you need it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to address this one level up. So if for example

```
<?php
namespace Fooman/Namespace;

class Example {

    protected $product;

    public function __construct(
         Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
    )
    {
        $this->product = $product;
    }
}
```

You could mock the product property like this:

```
$productMock = $this->getMock(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::class, [], [], '', false);

$objectManager = new \Magento\Framework\TestFramework\Unit\Helper\ObjectManager($this);

$example = $objectManager->getObject(
    'Fooman/Namespace/Example',
    ['product'=>$productMock]
);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the valuable information.